# Place UISearchBar above tableview but not in tableview or navbar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a UISearchBar and a UITableView on a view controller in my storyboard. The search bar is above the tableview so that it does not scroll. My problem is that the initialization of a UISearchController creates its own SearchBar instance that is not the same as the one I have manually added and positioned on my storyboard.

How do I set my storyboard SearchBar to be the one created for me by my UISearchController?

```
class ITSearchController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    // So that the search results are displayed in the current controllers table view
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true

        // This didn't work
        //var view = self.view.viewWithTag(777)
        //view = searchController.searchBar

        // This works but isn't what I want
        //tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        // This works but places it in the nav section. Not what I want.
        // self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

        // This is what I want but doesn't work. Basically make the search bar on my storyboard equal to the one created.
        searchBar = searchController.searchBar

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the search bar you have placed on the storyboard with `UISearchController` since UISearchController provides its own storyboard.

As an alternative, replace the search bar in the storyboard with a `UIView` and then add the search bar provided by the `UISearchController` as a subview to that `UIView`.

```
class ITSearchController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchView: UIView! // make this UIView

// So that the search results are displayed in the current controllers table view
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true

    // This should work
    searchView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)

}
}
```

This would give you the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I used. Seems like you should be able to specify an existing SearchBar via the constructor. I guess the storyboard magic always has to end somewhere...